# Import a PBF file from PyQGIS to QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I need to import this PBF file (this is how I can import it from QGIS not PyQGIS):

[image: pbf file]

I have tried to import like this:

```
url = r'type=xyz&url=https://vt-btn.idee.es/1.0.0/btn/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf'
   
print(url)
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(url, 'BTN_Completa', 'wms')  

if rlayer.isValid():
    print("Ok")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
else:
    print('invalid layer')
    print(rlayer.error().summary())
```

However, it does not import like when I import it from QGIS directly.

How can do that?

Comment: Please add the URL to your question

Comment: Added to the code

Answer (score 1):

I have used a QgsVectorTileLayer instance to import pbf:

```
url = r'type=xyz&url=https://vt-btn.idee.es/1.0.0/btn/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf' 
vectorTile = QgsVectorTileLayer(url, "a")
project.addMapLayer(vectorTile, True)
```

Variable project is an instance of QgsProject.
This is the result:
[image: a vector tile in QGIS]

Comment: Did you figure out how to load the style as well?